# Go function types that return structs being used with interfaces

Tags: function, go

I have a struct in a package that has time consuming methods on it and is also time consuming to construct via it's factory function.  Therefore, in the package that depends on this other struct I would like to be able to test it using both a fake factory function and a fake struct once it has been created.  As the struct is constructed via a factory function I would like to fake the factory function and pass an alternative factory function into my struct during testing time.

An example of the expensive package would be:

```
package expensive

import "fmt"

type myStruct struct{}

func (m *myStruct) DoSomething() {
    fmt.Println("In Do something")
}

func (m *myStruct) DoSomethingElse() {
    fmt.Println("In do something else")
}

// CreateInstance is expensive to call
func CreateInstance() *myStruct {
    return &myStruct{}
}
```

My main package that uses this then looks like this:

```
package main

import "play/expensive"

func main() {
    thing := structToConstruct{expensive.CreateInstance}
    thing.performAction()
}

type myInterface interface {
    DoSomething()
}

type structToConstruct struct {
    factoryFunction func() myInterface
}

func (s *structToConstruct) performAction() {
    instance := s.factoryFunction()
    instance.DoSomething()
}
```

However, this code complains with the error:

> .\main.go:6: cannot use expensive.CreateInstance (type func() *expensive.myStruct) as type func() myInterface in field value

However, *expensive.myStruct **does** implement the myInterface interface so I do not understand why Go is complaining about the type safety of this setup.

I've since realised after @jmaloney guideance that I could just wrapper my function like this in my main method:

```
    wrapper := func() myInterface {
        return expensive.CreateInstance()
    }
    thing := structToConstruct{wrapper}
```

and this then works but I still don't really understand why I can't use a struct that implements an interface when a function is expecting an instance of that interface to be returned especially when no type assertion/conversion is necessary on this fix as it is simply just calling the underlying factory function.

EDIT: I've since come across this proposal to add this to the language. The proposal was rejected:

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12754

Comment: Added a hopefully useful explanation to my answer to your updated question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getInstance` needs to return `myInterface`

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var function func() myInterface

    function = getInstance

    newSomething := function()

    newSomething.doSomething()
}

type myInterface interface {
    doSomething()
}

type myStruct struct{}

func (m *myStruct) doSomething() {
    fmt.Println("doing something")
}

func getInstance() myInterface {
    return &myStruct{}
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/wELpmo204Y)

> However, *expensive.myStruct does implement the myInterface interface so I do not understand why Go is complaining about the type safety of this setup.

In that instance you were not dealing with Go's interfaces you were dealing with the type signature of your struct.

when you first declared your struct with `factoryFunction func() *myFunction` factoryFunction now always needs to match the declared signature.

Comment: Thanks jmaloney, unfortunately in my real code this is not possible as the "getInstance" function lives in another package. Also the "myStruct" does more than just the one method so would not want to restrict the factory method to produce just the limited interface that the calling code in this one use case needs.

Comment: Any more details you can provide? It's hard to think about without more context.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @jmaloney, I've reworded the question and the example to be more accurate of my situation so hopefully this will help. In doing so I've also worked out a way to get it working but I still don't understand why the Go type system won't let me just do it using the function that returns the struct so any guideance on that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

See if this might help, have a function which returns an interface given the struct.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var instance myInterface

    // The return value of the getInstance function can be assigned to a variable
    // of type myInterface
    instance = getInstance()

    var function func(*myStruct) myInterface

    // But the function itself can't be assigned to a variable for a function
    // that returns a myInterface.  You get:
    // cannot use getInstance (type func() *myStruct) as type func() myInterface in assignment
    function = getMyInstance
    r := function(instance.(*myStruct))
    r.doSomething()
}

type myInterface interface {
    doSomething()
}

type myStruct struct{}

func (m *myStruct) doSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Done something")

}

func getInstance() *myStruct {
    return &myStruct{}
}

func getMyInstance(myInst *myStruct) myInterface {
    return myInst

}
```

Available at https://play.golang.org/p/h8iJ0i-Xym