# Functions as members in structures

Tags: function, go, struct, field

I am trying to make function as a member in my structure

```
type myStruct struct {
    myFun func(interface{}) interface{}
}
func testFunc1(b bool) bool {
    //some functionality here
    //returns a boolean at the end
}
func testFunc2(s string) int {
    //some functionality like measuring the string length
    // returns an integer indicating the length
}
func main() {
    fr := myStruct{testFunc1}
    gr := myStruct{testFunc2}
}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Cannot use testFunc (type func(b bool) bool) as type func(interface{}) interface{}
Inspection info: Reports composite literals with incompatible types and values.
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code's problem is the incompatible types between the declaration in the struct and `testFunc`. A function taking `interface{}` and returning `interface{}` doesn't have the same type as a function taking and returning `bool`, so the initialization fails. The compiler error message you pasted is right on point here.

---

This will work:

```
package main

type myStruct struct {
    myFun func(bool) bool
}

func testFunc(b bool) bool {
    //some functionality here
    //returns a boolean at the end
    return true
}

func main() {
    fr := myStruct{testFunc}
}
```

Comment: I want the structure instances to be able to store functions of any signature, which is why I used `interface{}` as the argument and return types. Is there a different way of doing that? I have updated the question to indicate the same

Comment: @Murky: that will not work, as Go doesn't have generics at this time [there's a proposal in progress for Go 2: https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/master/design/go2draft-generics-overview.md]. The only way to accomplish it right now is have your actual functions also use `interface{}` for everything and do the runtime dispatch with type switches. Alternatively, change the design - it's very possible your real issue is solvable using idiomatic Go constructs like interfaces

Comment: @Murky, the answer to your question [is in the FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types). Also consider reading [this](https://blog.merovius.de/2018/06/03/why-doesnt-go-have-variance-in.html).

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up EliBendersky, @kostix. I am marking the question solved.

Comment: @Murky, I recommend you to ponder the idea about interfaces, and `interface{}` in particular a bit more. [This excellent explanation](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces) of interfaces is a bit outdated but 99.9% correct, and it will explain to you that `interface{}` is not merely a (kinda weirdly-looking) syntactic construct meaning "any type" but actually a rather concrete type: a struct with two pointer-sized fields. That's why `bool` (which is usually a platform-sized `int` internally) cannot be somehow automagically "be matched" by that struct; they have different undelying data layouts

Comment: Hi @Murky - this was also my first question on SO (or a slight variation)! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303611/go-function-types-that-return-structs-being-used-with-interfaces  After asking the question I came across this proposal to add it to the language which was closed but had an interesting discussion of the problem: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/12754

Comment: Compilable version of this code https://play.golang.org/p/_KC2Kz-7oRa.